# Android erro “android.app.Application does not implement dagger.android.HasActivityInjector”

Tags: android, injeção-de-dependência, mvvm

Estou a tentar executar a minha app e sempre que clico num botão e vai para a actividade Extended obtenho o seguinte erro:

```
Process: com.converter.android.dailycope, PID: 28573
          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.converter.android.dailycope/com.converter.android.dailycope.ui.extended.ExtendedActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.app.Application does not implement dagger.android.HasActivityInjector
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
           Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.app.Application does not implement dagger.android.HasActivityInjector
              at dagger.android.AndroidInjection.inject(AndroidInjection.java:48)
              at com.converter.android.dailycope.ui.base.BaseActivity.performDependencyInjection(BaseActivity.java:105)
              at com.converter.android.dailycope.ui.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:35)
              at com.converter.android.dailycope.ui.extended.ExtendedActivity.onCreate(ExtendedActivity.java:34)
              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
```

O erro acontece na linha onde tenho `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`

```
 public class ExtendedActivity extends BaseActivity<ActivityExtendedBinding, ExtendedViewModel> {

@Inject
ViewModelProvider.Factory mViewModelFactory;
ActivityExtendedBinding mActivityStartBinding;
private ExtendedViewModel mExtendedViewModel;

private String caps, horos, tipo;
private String data, prefString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
(...)
```

A classe onde tenho o HasActivityInjector:

```
public class Cope extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {

@Inject
DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    DaggerExtendedComponent.builder().application(this).build().inject(this);

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
    }

}
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o meu problema colocando `app:name` no `Manifest.xml`